# How to make a CMFCToolBar display its buttons' text label right to to their icons?

Tags: mfc

How to make a [`CMFCToolBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb984480.aspx) display its buttons' text labels right to their icons?

Because a `CMFCToolBar` is not a standard common control [Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb760435.aspx), I can't just set a [`TBSTYLE_LIST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb760439.aspx) flag to do it.

I can't use a [`CToolBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/69wz6ea1.aspx) or [`CToolBarCtrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/tf5d6ca2.aspx) instead because they don't work well with my [`CDockablePane`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb984433.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use [CreateEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/bb984019.aspx) and pass TBSTYLE_LIST as the dwCtrlStyle parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [CMFCToolBar::SetToolBarBtnText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28ViewControlDialogBar%2FCRemetToolBar%3A%3ASetToolBarBtnText%29;k%28afxtoolbar%2FCMFCToolBar%3A%3ASetToolBarBtnText%29;k%28CRemetToolBar%3A%3ASetToolBarBtnText%29;k%28CMFCToolBar%3A%3ASetToolBarBtnText%29;k%28SetToolBarBtnText%29;k%28DevLang-C%2B%2B%29;k%28TargetOS-Windows%29&rd=true) method. Toolbar must be created with TBSTYLE_FLAT control style.

```
if (m_MyToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1)) 
&&
MyToolBar.LoadToolBar(nToolBarResourceID))
{
  m_MyToolBar.SetToolBarBtnText( MyToolBar.CommandToIndex(ID_MY_CMD), _T("My command"));
}
```

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [EnableTextLabels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb984421.aspx) function of the `CMFCToolBar` -- says "Enables or disables text labels under toolbar button images"

Comment: I want the text label to show on the right side of button image, not under it.

Comment: I've taken a look at the source code of the `CMFCToolbar` class (afxtoolbar.cpp), there doesn't seem to be any possibility of having the text to the right -- it even disables text display when the toolbar is docked to the left of the window

Answer (score 0):

Those classes were ported from the BCG toolkit.  The documentation is pretty poor.  You should be able to set the button class public member variable *m_bText* to true and set the text in *m_strText*.